# Difference between contentResolver and ContentObserver

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application that receives MMS and I read a lot of code.  And there is contentResolver and ContentObserver, but I do not get what is the difference between them

Like this statement:

`contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms"), true, mmsObserver);`

`contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(mmsObserver);`

What is the difference between contentResolver and ContentObserver and what do they have to do with receiving MMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ContentProvider as the name suggests provides you **a handle or a reference** (generally a cursor)to a data set  so that you can work with its data

ContentObserver is used to **get notified** if the data residing in the data set **has changed**. So it is used to [*observe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) the data source for changes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok i got the observe but what is the contentResolver?

Comment: [This is the documentation link for contentResolver.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html)  See also [this guide that discusses content providers.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you told me please if i am right or not, it is for access to MMS content, so we can read it and show it in my application, am i right?